# kill %1 equivalent in fish

Tags: kill, job-control, fish

In bash, if I run `kill %1`, it kills a backgrounded command in the current shell (the most recent one, I believe).

Is there an equivalent of this in fish? I haven't been able to find it online in a bit of web searching.

I'm not sure if I did it wrong, but

```
$ ps
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
  73911 pts/5    00:00:00 fish
  73976 pts/5    00:00:00 ps
$ sleep 100
^Z⏎
$ kill %1
$ ps
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
  73911 pts/5    00:00:00 fish
  74029 pts/5    00:00:00 sleep
  74121 pts/5    00:00:00 ps
```

Comment: It's not explicit in the [current fish docs](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/), but in [v2.6](https://fishshell.com/docs/2.6/index.html) there's "if the string is the ID of a job, the result is the process group ID of the job" with the example "kill -s SIGINT %3 will send the SIGINT signal to the job with job ID 3."

Comment: I just ran fish to test this, and it worked as expected. Can you show an example where it didn't work as expected? Maybe include version information, too.

Comment: In `fish`, have a read of `man jobs`. It's short, so easy to read.  It _sounds_ like it contains what you need.

Comment: I added an example where it didn't seem to work

Comment: Best not to make assumptions about the ordering of job ids in any shell. Your bash conjecture is certainly invalid -- it would involve renumbering every other running job as each new job starts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your command has worked, but because the job is stopped it has not responded to the signal.

From your example where it didn't seem to work, try continuing the process with `fg` or `bg`, or forcibly terminate the process with `kill -SIGKILL %1`, and it will exit.

`kill %1` works immediately in bash and zsh because it is a builtin command in these shells and sends `SIGCONT` in addition to `SIGTERM` (or the specified signal).

Answer (score 0):

The `jobs` fish command can show the id/group of the command jobs.
To get the latest job id you want to run `(jobs -gl)` emulates the `%1` in zsh/bash

hence

```
kill (jobs -lg)
```

will do the trick